# net core 2.0 xunit Controller with dependency injection using Mock is null

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, moq, xunit

I am doing an `Net Core 2.0 Rest Api` application.

I am using dependency injection with Interface `IContactBiz` and class `ContactBiz`.

IContactBiz is defined like this

```
public interface IContactBiz
{
    ReturnModel Add(List<ContactEntity> lstContactEntity, ContactEntity contact); 
}
```

My ContactBiz class

```
public class ContactBiz: IContactBiz
{   
    public ReturnModel Add(List<ContactEntity> lstContactEntity, ContactEntity contact)
    {
        contact.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        lstContactEntity.Add(contact);
        return new ReturnModel()
        {
            Result = true,
        };
     }
}
```

It is set in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{  
    services.AddSingleton<IContactBiz, ContactBiz>();
}
```

I have a ContactController, defined like this

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    private readonly IContactBiz _contactBiz;

    public ContactController(IContactBiz contactbiz)
    {
        _contactBiz = contactbiz;
    }

   //...
```

I have Post Method on my controller where i call Add() method from `ContactBiz` class

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]ContactModel contact)
{
    ReturnModel errorModel = new ReturnModel();

    //...

    errorModel = _contactBiz.Add(lstContactEntity, contactEntity);

    //...
 }
```

When I run it with Postman, it works fine.. I reach Add() method from ContactBiz.cs and retrieve data.

But I have a `xUnit` project to test it, and I want to use Moq..

I have

```
public class ContactControllerTest
{
    ContactController _controller;
    public ContactControllerTest()
    {
        Mock<IContactBiz> mockRepo = new Mock<IContactBiz>();
        _controller = new ContactController(contactbiz: mockRepo.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void InsertContact()
    {
        ContactModel cm = new ContactModel()
        {
            Address = "data",
            City = "data",
            Company = "data",
            Email = "data",
            Name = "data",
            PhonePersonal = "data",
            PhoneWork = "data",
            State = "data",
            BirthDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-30)
        };
        var actionResult = _controller.Post(cm);
    }
}
```

I run it in debug mode...

When I reach the line 
`errorModel = _contactBiz.Add(lstContactEntity, contactEntity);` in Post() method.. is null...

Add() method from the class ContactBiz it is never called

I think i am missing to set which class has is mapped to `_contactBiz` interface

the line I have in startup.cs

`services.AddSingleton<IContactBiz, ContactBiz>();` 
Do not have access to Add() method por ContactBiz class, and `errorModel` is null.

I think the problem is that I did not I assign `services.AddSingleton<IContactBiz, ContactBiz>();` in Moq?

Is there another problem?

Thanks

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight ***exactly*** what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the ***actual*** problem.

Comment: Nkosi, sorry for my explanation... i just arrange some comments.. Thanks

Comment: You need to show the subject under test. most of the details have been left out. The added comments do not provide any more detail about what the code does.

Comment: Nkosi, I just added all the steps i m doing, My controller and test unit... Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the mock to behave as expected when invoked

```
ReturnModel returnModel = new ReturnModel() {
    Result = true,
};
Mock<IContactBiz> mockRepo = new Mock<IContactBiz>();
mockRepo
    .Setup(_ => _.Add(It.IsAny<List<ContactEntity>>(), It.IsAny<ContactEntity>()))
    .Return(returnModel);

_controller = new ContactController(contactbiz: mockRepo.Object);
```

otherwise it will return the default value of the return type