# net core xunit do not step into method using dependecy injection

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, moq, xunit

I am doing a `net core rest api` application where I want to use `xunit` to test it.

I have an interface called IContact with a simple method, and a Concrete class called Contact

```
public interface IContact
{
   int Get();
}

public class Contact: IContact
{
  public int Get()
  {
     return 10;
  }
}
```

In startup.cs I defined this...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IContact, Contact>();
}
```

I use the default Values Controller like this

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
   private IContact _contact;
   public ValuesController(IContact contact)
   {
      _contact = contact;
   }
   [HttpGet]
   public void Get()
   {
     int aa = _contact.Get();
   }
}
```

I have a xunit project where i am using Moq to call Get() Method()

```
public class UnitTest1
{
   ValuesController _controller;
   public UnitTest1()
   {
       Mock<IContact> mockRepo = new Mock<IContact>();
       _controller = new ValuesController(mockRepo.Object);
    }
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
       _controller.Get();
    }
}
```

I run this test in Debug mode and when reach line

```
int aa = _contact.Get();
```

The problem I have is that it does not step into `Get()` method from `Contact` class. It returns 0;

What i am missing?

Where do I set interface IContact has to call Contact class as I defined in startup.cs?

Comment: How is this different to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60747253/5233410)?

Comment: And as I explained in the previous question you would need to setup the mock to behave as expected when invoked.

Comment: Hi Nkosi, it is almost the same question with an easer example. What do you mean with I need to set up the mock to bahave I expected? If my method returns 10.. I have to set up  the mock to return 10? it is like implement all the core business again... Thanks

Comment: It is like faking the result without having to implement the logic again.

Comment: Thanks, what I want to test is Get() method from my Controller... Get() method from my Contact class, can return different values depend on some validation... I want to test it. Do I have to assume a return value from a method I want to test? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I have is that it does not step into Get() method from Contact class. It returns 0

You need to setup the mock to behave as expected when invoked.

Because if you don't, the mock will not know what to do when invoked.

```
Mock<IContact> mockRepo = new Mock<IContact>();
//setup the mock to behave as exptected.
mockRepo.Setup(_ => _.Get()).Returns(10); 
//pass mocked instance to subject under test
_controller = new ValuesController(mockRepo.Object); 

//...exercise subject under test
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what i though, but what i mean is that what happend  If my Get() method have some logic, and can returns 10 o 100, how can I handle it? Thanks